# how to make turret only shoot when pressing in specific location?

Tags: unity, c#

im using this code to shoot bullets from turrets, it is working perfectly but what i want to do is that, if i ll click mouse at the bottom of it it will still shoot i want it to only shoot if i will click on those positions i ll attach image to explain what i want to do here is my code:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shoot : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody2D projectile;
    public Transform fireTransform;
    public GameObject missilePrefab;
    public float fireForce = 90000;
    public Transform projectileSpawnPoint;
    public float projectileVelocity;
    public float timeBetweenShots;
    private float timeBetweenShotsCounter;
    private bool canShoot;
    protected Animation Animation;

    void Awake() {
        Animation = GetComponent<Animation> (); 
    }
    void Start () {
        canShoot = false;
        timeBetweenShotsCounter = timeBetweenShots;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canShoot)
        {
            GameObject missile = Instantiate(missilePrefab, fireTransform.position, transform.rotation);
            Animation.Play ();
            Rigidbody2D missileBody = missile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent < AudioSource > ();
            audio.PlayOneShot ((AudioClip)Resources.Load ("sh"));
            missileBody.AddForce(transform.forward * fireForce);
            canShoot = false;
        }
        if (!canShoot)
        {
            timeBetweenShotsCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            if(timeBetweenShotsCounter <= 0)
            {
                Animation.Stop ();
                canShoot = true;
                timeBetweenShotsCounter = timeBetweenShots;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: my image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting your code in an `if (mouseClicked ...)`, put it in a public function. Then on your scene, create a UI element (probably a button), move it around the screen to the desired location, then on the Inspector, set its `OnClick()` action by pressing the `+` button, then drag and drop your turret's object on the field that appears, and from the bar choose `MyTurretScript -> MyShootingFunction`. This should only trigger when you click the UI button on the screen.

Alternatively, if you want your button to be in a 3D scene (so that it scrolls together with the camera for example) you can create an object, give it a `Collider` and also a script that looks like this:

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    myTurrentScript.MyFireFunction();
}
```

Please note I used example names, replace them as needed.

Edit:

Instead of

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && canShoot)
    {
        GameObject missile = Instantiate(missilePrefab, fireTransform.position, transform.rotation);
        Animation.Play ();
        Rigidbody2D missileBody = missile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent < AudioSource > ();
        audio.PlayOneShot ((AudioClip)Resources.Load ("sh"));
        missileBody.AddForce(transform.forward * fireForce);
        canShoot = false;
    }
    if (!canShoot)
    {
        timeBetweenShotsCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeBetweenShotsCounter <= 0)
        {
            Animation.Stop ();
            canShoot = true;
            timeBetweenShotsCounter = timeBetweenShots;
        }
    }
}
```

Do

```
void Update () {
    if (!canShoot)
    {
        timeBetweenShotsCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeBetweenShotsCounter <= 0)
        {
            Animation.Stop ();
            canShoot = true;
            timeBetweenShotsCounter = timeBetweenShots;
        }
    }
}

public void Shoot() {
    if (canShoot)
    {
        GameObject missile = Instantiate(missilePrefab, fireTransform.position, transform.rotation);
        Animation.Play ();
        Rigidbody2D missileBody = missile.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent < AudioSource > ();
        audio.PlayOneShot ((AudioClip)Resources.Load ("sh"));
        missileBody.AddForce(transform.forward * fireForce);
        canShoot = false;
    }
}
```

Now other objects on the scene can call `myTurret.Shoot()` in order to attempt to shoot a missile (if `canShoot` is `true`).

Comment: problem with that idea is that i dont want to put button in my screen, im making game for android device

Comment: You can always make it invisible, but the logic is still there, just put a solid color with zero alpha, the `OnClick` will still work.

Comment: can you just show me how i should put this code in public function ? im beginner in unity and c#

Comment: @Nikka I edited my answer with code

Comment: thanks it works it is shooting but now projectile (missile) is only shooting at up, not where turret is rotated

Comment: @Nikka if you do `missile.Rotate( Vector3.right );` exactly after `Instantiate` what happens?